# Faulty presentation of the users that earned the "Copy Editor" badge

Tags: bug, design, layout

When [clicking](https://android.stackexchange.com/badges/33/copy-editor) to see the users that have earned the "copy editor" badge, there's two issues with the layout:

1. The space between the first and second name is way larger than the space between the second and third name.
2. The bronze badges of the third name aren't visible, but are present at the source.

[image: screenshot composition]

I see this behaviour for the list of users that [earned other badges](https://android.stackexchange.com/badges/37/famous-question) <sup>1</sup> as well, but here, there's no reason as to why the space can't be optimized, since clearly the large blank space between the first and second name could be equalized with the blank space between the second and third name, thus leading to the presentation of the third name bronze badges count.

<sup>1) Easily justified by the questions with huge names, where only a layout change would fix the issue...</sup>

**Screenshot from Google Chrome**

With Google Chrome or Internet Explorer, the first number starts to appear.

[image: Screenshot from Google Chrome]

Comment: confirmed, happening with me too.